# Remove Adjacent duplicate from a string keeping only one instance: java

Tags: java, string, comparison

It is difficult to say in words so i ll use examples. Consider following inputs:-

```
Input String  =  AABBSTUUUX
Output String =  ABSTUX
```

How to achieve this in java.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
String word = "AABBSTUUUX";

for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1)) {
        word.deleteCharAt(i + 1);
    }
}

System.out.println(word);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

1. Scan the String from first to last
2. Add each character in in a `char` type variable `temp`
3. Compare each character to the temp except for the first (marked by index 0) character and delete the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

An implementation similar to @Razib's solution above:

```
public String removeDupes(String in) {

  if (in == null || in.length() <= 1) {
    return in;
  }

  char lastLetter = in.charAt(0);
  String out = String.valueOf(lastLetter);
  for (int i = 1; i < in.length(); i++) {
    char nextLetter = in.charAt(i);
    if (nextLetter != lastLetter) {
      out += nextLetter;
    }
    lastLetter = nextLetter;
  }

  return out;
}
```

Obviously, this is case-sensitive and will remove duplicate non-word characters as well.